# Saving Raw_input to a list when used in a While Loop

Tags: python

I have already posted a question today and it had 2 problems on it. One of which was solved perfectly, then it got a little complicated. So forgive me but I am posting the other question separately as it confused some peeps:

I am new to python so apologies in advance. Any help is much appreciated. I have been stuck on this code for 2weeks now and I have tunnel vision and cannot work it out:

Basically our assignment was to get to grips with Object-Oriented Programming. We unfortunately have to use "get" and "set" which I've learnt a lot of people dislike, however, as per our tutor we have to do it like that. We were told tp create a program whereby the user is presented with a screen with 3 options. 1. adding a student. 2. viewing a student and 3. removing a student.. within my AddStudent function I have to ask the user to enter fname Lname age degree studying id number (these are the easy bits) and also module name and grade for each module, I have managed to create a loop whereby it will ask the user over and over to enter modules and corresponding grades and will break from said loop when the user enters -1 into the modulname field. However, when trying saving it to a list named students[]  ... (which is at the very top of my code above all functions, to apparently make it global) it saves all input from the user re: age name etc but when it comes to saving module names and grades it only saves the last input and not the multiple inputs I need it to. I am unsure if it is within my AddStudent function where it isn't saving or within my ViewStudent function: Both are below (remember I HAVE to use the GET and SET malarky) ;)

```
students[] # Global List

def addStudent():
    print 
    print "Adding student..."
    student = Student()
    firstName = raw_input("Please enter the student's first name: ")
    lastName = raw_input("Please enter the student's last name: ")
    degree = raw_input("Please enter the name of the degree the student is studying: ")
    studentid = raw_input("Please enter the students ID number: ")
    age = raw_input("Please enter the students Age: ")

    while True:
        moduleName = raw_input("Please enter module name: ") 
        if moduleName == "-1":
            break
        grade = raw_input ("Please enter students grade for " + moduleName+": ")

    student.setFirstName(firstName) # Set this student's first name
    student.setLastName(lastName)
    student.setDegree(degree)# Set this student's last name
    student.setGrade(grade)
    student.setModuleName(moduleName)
    student.setStudentID(studentid)
    student.setAge(age)
    students.append(student)
    print "The student",firstName+' '+lastName,"ID number",studentid,"has been added to the system."
```

........................

```
def viewStudent():
    print "Printing all students in database : "

    for person in students:
            print "Printing details for: " + person.getFirstName()+" "+ person.getLastName()
            print "Age: " + person.getAge()
            print "Student ID: " + person.getStudentID()
            print "Degree: " + person.getDegree()
            print "Module: " + person.getModuleName()
            print "Grades: " + person.getGrade()
```

Comment: Tell your tutor s/he is an idiot who needs to learn Python isn't Java.

Comment: hahahahaha! sooo many people say this! Apparently my tutor's a very clever guy but it's the way he HAS to teach us! :)

Comment: Obviously not your fault, but it is a real problem - a big part of Python is readability and maintainability, this kind of using Python as though it were another language seriously hurts that. It pains me to see new programmers being lead down bad paths by people meant to be teaching them best practices.

Comment: yeh that's what we were told when starting the course and I enjoyed it  and was quite confident with it, until all this new stuff was introduced and now i'm just so stuck and don't understand how to sort the problem I have! I've tried logical thinking and now am just button bashing hoping for the best haha!

Comment: you should try learning python from the python docs on your own. you will probably learn more than you are in this class of yours. http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/

Comment: Thanks! so much for university courses eh! :)

Comment: as a wise man said: “I have never let my learning get in the way of my education.” – Mark Twain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem is that the module is a single variable you keep changing. instead, make it a list.

```
while True:
        moduleName = raw_input("Please enter module name: ") 
        if moduleName == "-1":
            break
        grade = raw_input ("Please enter students grade for " + moduleName+": ")
```

should be something like

```
modules = []

while True:
        moduleName = raw_input("Please enter module name: ") 
        if moduleName == "-1":
            break
        grade = raw_input ("Please enter students grade for " + moduleName+": ")
        modules.append((moduleName, grade))
```

add a new variable to `student` which is "Modules" and is a list.

and then `modules` will be a list of tuples which are `(moduleName, grade)` and to display them, change the line in `viewstudent` from:

```
        print "Module: " + person.getModuleName()
        print "Grades: " + person.getGrade()
```

to:

```
for module, grade in person.getModules():
       print "Module: " + module
       print "Grades: " + grade
```

Comment: Thanks! I changed it and I just keep getting this error message! I'm beginning to think maybe it's impossible :S   --- viewStudent()
  File "/Users/Rusowicz/Desktop/Uni/Python/python classes.py", line 122, in viewStudent
    for module, grade in person.getModuleName():
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack  ----- When I tried it as for module, grade in person.getModules(): --- the error says getmodules doesn't exist etc

Comment: of course, you need to add it. since you did not provide the code for `Student` i could not help you there. but you need to remove the seperate `Module` and `Grade` attributes of the `Student` and instead give him a `Modules` attribute which is a list. after you loop them, you can do `student.setModules(modules)` and then you have your `person.getModules()`

Comment: I think this is where i've messed up I was told to add that student = Student() there is no code for it, I am actually not quite sure why it is there all I do know is that when I take it away it gives me the error msg: student.setFirstName(firstName) # Set this student's first name
NameError: global name 'student' is not defined

Comment: of course, if there is not variable `student` how do you want to modify it? it seems to me that you are not learning python properly at all if you are expected to make this kind of application without a basic understanding of variables or classes. if you cant understand your own code, how can we help you? i recommend you come back to StackOverflow once you can appreciate the answers we are helping you with.

Comment: apologies! I can now print all grades it's just the modules i cannot print. I do have a basic understanding and I am trying my hardest to learn. There just seem to be so many different ways and I do appreciate the answers, it's just i've looked at that many didfferent things now and have noone to help as off uni for another two weeks i've got myself mega confused. thanks anyways

Comment: p.s ... I've actually done it =D your help and answers are very much appreciated! walking away from the computer and writing it on a notepad seemed to help me Thhhhaaaaaanks!!!

Comment: @Lauren i'm glad it helped you, but i still think you should probably learn some more python or at least learn it properly before committing yourself to asking people on StackOverflow for help. sometimes you will get answers you do not understand, and then you will not be able to help yourself.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need something like this:

```
modules = {}

while True:
    module_name = raw_input("Please enter module name: ") 
    if module_name:
        grade = raw_input ("Please enter students grade for " + module_name +": ")
        modules[module_name] = grade
```

Modules is a dictionary ("hash map"  in other languages), each mod name is key and grades are values, or you could also do it with tuples, wherever floats your boat.

Instead of checking for -1 as a stop condition you check if is true, in python anything empty is evaluated to false.